# Rails : test if object is ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How could I test if `var` is an ActiveRecord object ?

I tried

```
if var[:id]
  # ==> Activerecord
else
  # ==> Other object
end
```

But I get `TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer`.

Comment: please show us what `var` is

Comment: Well, I have an Hash and I want to map key and values with different behaviour if it's an active record object or a native one (string, integer etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can check the ancestors of your class like so:

```
var.class.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

or you can just compare the two classes:

```
if var.class < ActiveRecord::Base
  # do something
end
```